# configuring munin-node for nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, monitoring, munin

I am deploying munin to monitor my production ubuntu aws ec2 instances which is running on nginx. Now I wanna deploy munin-node in the production system and deploy munin-master in the another aws ec2 ubuntu instance. Most of the blog speaks about configuring munin with apache2 web server but not with nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step tutorial how to set it up on ec2 with nginx only:
http://littlepea12.tumblr.com/post/45911132737/munin-setup-for-monitoring-django-on-ec2-instance-with

Answer (score 0):

I have recently setup munin to monitor nginx [this from github](https://github.com/jnstq/munin-nginx-ubuntu).

Comment: I checked it long back, my munin node is running in nginx based aws ec2 instance and I need to config munin master in apache2 based ec2 ubuntu instance. let me know how I do configure munin-node(client-side) on nginx

Comment: ooh right. Sorry, like this then [this](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2011/06/munin-monitor-debian-squeeze-server/). This guide shows you running munin on nginx using debian which is a very similar setup to yours.

Comment: let me try this then I will get back to you, I am very specific to munin-node not the master,this article have not explained any thing about munin-node configuration.